# Why S3 Bucket upload showing Options Request Denied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am practicing AWS S3, tried to upload a simple image file to S3 bucket in US East (N. Virginia) region . file has uploaded but its not showing successful instead it says there is an error.

Options request denied 100% . what is that and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: no code , just created a new bucket and uploaded a file.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that it's a Problem with Safari Browser settings.
When I tried to upload files by using Chrome browser , it uploaded with no error and with HTTP code 200.